# Mouse lags on HDD activity

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, mouse

My mouse lags very badly, when HDD activity happens. (I have Microsoft Desktop 6000 Wireless mouse)
Any ideas?

Comment: You could buy an SSD! :D

Comment: Funny comment, but might be true... Your hard disk might have worn out and thus causes a lot of interrupts. Does this also occur when you move the mouse around when your computer is idle? Do you see any weird behaviour in the Task Manager or the Resource Monitor?

Comment: No, I've checked my HDD and it's ok. And no, there are no any lags when PC is idle.
Probably the problem is with some system resources sharing, but I don't know what to check.

Comment: Any interference or anything which basically reduce signal anyway but its fine until hard load occurs?

Answer (score 2):

My own solution to the problem of lag with wireless mouse, is not to use one.

If you want your mouse to be responsive under conditions of heavy use, use a USB mouse.

I just remark that a PS2 mouse is even more responsive, but very few computers today have the outlet.

(The above reflects my personal experience, and might not be valid for all computer/mouse/driver combinations.)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to buy a USB extender cable so the transmitter is placed further away from the PC case.

When there was a lot of activity on my HDDs, the mouse started lagging/stuttering. Anyone with this problem should give it a try. Could be your PC components interfering with the wireless USB mouse.

Answer (score 2):

moving the USB wireless dongle from the back of my PC to the USB hub I have at the other end of my desk worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with a Logitech Performance MX wireless mouse, which uses Logitech's Unifying Receiver.

Even though the receiver was only 2.5 feet from the mouse I was getting a lot of interference and jittering. Moving the receiver to my keyboard USB hub, which is about 0.5 feet away, fixed the problem entirely.

I think the underlying issue may be more related to Wifi interference though, as the unifying receiver transmits in the 2.4GHz frequency range used by 802.11B.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Windows Device Manager.  Look for any red flags/indicators on any of the device icons.  Pay particular attention to the disk drives and controllers.  A flag here could indicate a resource conflict or a driver problem.  I'm not sure whether this is still the case with Windows 7, but in earlier Windows versions, when a 32-bit disk driver somehow failed, Windows would revert to a 16-bit generic driver and the result was terrible performance and weird effects such as you describe.  The solution may be a matter of finding and installing the correct disk system driver for the affected component, which might be the motherboard.

How to access the Device Manager in Windows 7:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/device-manager-cm-windows-7.htm

It's also possible that it's a power-related issue.  Disk access causes a spike in power use, potentially leaving peripheral devices (like a wireless USB mouse) with less power.  But this is very unlikely; unless you have a lot of other power-hungry peripherals and/or an undersized power supply, it would tend to point to a faulty power supply.